# How to find an outline of a 3D shape projection (including holes)?

Tags: geometry, polygons

I have a projection of a 3D shape (mesh) onto a plane. I know all point coordinates and how they are connected into line segments. How do I find the outline (polygon) of this shape and outlines of holes inside it?

I understand that it will also include calculations of intersection points between non-related line segments (coming from different parts of the mesh that overlap in the projection).

Is there a standard algorithm for this problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b65O9.png)

Comment: Yes, the algorithm for a shadow is simply: $f :: R\times R \times R\rightarrow 2, g::R \times R\rightarrow 2: f(x,y,z)=true \Rightarrow g(x,y)=true$. (assumption is that your projection is $(x,y,z)\rightarrow(x,y)$).

Comment: I don't really understand what means

Comment: I think you’ll need a union algorithm. See for instance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vatti_clipping_algorithm

Comment: Is your projection issued from a  common center or a projection with this common center at infinity, i.e., orthogonal (or oblique) parallel projection ?

Comment: @jean - no it's a perspective camera and the object is not necessarily at the center of its frustum, nor the object is symmetrical

Comment: @lhf  - thank you, I'll have a look

Comment: some scanline algorithms that sort the edge positions in each scanline might work ok.